# Knockout accordion bindings break

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, binding, knockout.js

The following binding worked prior to 1.9:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.accordion = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor() || {};
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(element).accordion(options);
        }, 0);
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function(){
            $(element).accordion("destroy");
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor() || {};
        $(element).accordion("destroy").accordion(options);
    }
}
```

But since 1.9, it no longer works, and the following error is given:

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on accordion prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'
```

I'm having trouble figuring out why. I looked over the jQuery UI upgrade notes, but nothing seemed relevant.

What's causing this, and what about my binding needs to change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on accordion prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

This error says that you are calling `destroy` method of accordion widget before initializing the widget.

The issue is with your custom binding code where you use `setTimeOut`. The code inside setTimeOut runs after your update function. So the accordion plugin is not initialized over your element and in your update function you are calling `destroy` method of the accordion.

A simple alternative is you should check whether accordion plugin is initialized over the element or not before calling any method, like :

```
if(typeof $(element).data("ui-accordion") != "undefined"){
 $(element).accordion("destroy").accordion(options);
}
```

Here you can check [**Working jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/ijibef/1/edit).

Comment: Funny that you called a JS Bin a fiddle : )

Comment: @PWKad and I changed that :D to jsbin :D