# jQuery UI not applying after using KnockoutJS with koExternalTemplateEngine

Tags: jquery-ui, templates, knockout.js, template-engine

I have this simple js that loads data from web api, applies bindings via knockout and applies jQuery UI widget.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    infuser.defaults.templateSuffix = ".tmpl.html";
    infuser.defaults.templateUrl = "Templates";

    $.get("data.json")
        .done(function(data) {
            ko.applyBindings(data);
            $(".accordion").accordion();
        });
});
```

When I have my templates in the main html file, all is working properly.

But when I move templates into separate files and load them via koExternalTemplateEngine.js, templates are loaded properly but jQueryUI is not applied.
jQueryUI works ok, as I can invoke this in the browser console and all is back.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by using a custom binding for the accordion ([see this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036343/knockout-js-and-jqueryui-to-create-an-accordion-menu)) and see if that fixes the problem.  My guess is that its a timing issue between loading the external template, applying the bindings and then the jQuery accordion call (specifically, I think the accordion HTML is not fully loaded/built at the time the jQuery call is made to initialize it).

Comment: I have found inside the infuser library that it uses ajax.get to load the templates by default. It works ok when I force it to not do this via ajax. Still now I have to figure out if in the ajax version there is a handler/promise for complete or something.